# How does Visual Studio know which .C files to compile?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio

How does Visual Studio choose which .C files to compile and link,  and which ones to ignore?

Can Visual Studio compile an .H file before it compiles a .C file?

Do the answers to the above questions, change for .CPP and .HPP files?

*Let's assume, that .H and .C files never include another .C file and that .H files contain only declarations.*

Comment: Header files aren’t compiled, they are included in other source files. Source files can be compiled in any order since they need to contain everything needed for compilation in them.

Comment: It doesn't matter which .c file is compiled first.

Comment: @Francois Well, they are compiled, but via the include mechanism.

Comment: All right, so the ORDER of compilation does not matter and each compilation unit is an island of its own...but what about the linking order? Also, what about my other question "How does it choose which .C files to compile and link ...and which to ignore?"

Comment: Usually the linker gets all compiled object files at once, so there is no need to specify an order, the linker will sort that out. I don't know Windows, but in Linux there a few cases when linking static libraries where you have to tell the linker which to use first. I don't know if the VS linker has this issue.

Comment: Which files it compiles depends on the build type. Visual studio can use msbuild vcxproj xml files that list all the files to compile or it can use nmake Makefiles or it can use other buildsystems. You should be more specific in the build system that you're talking about

Comment: @PeterT: I meant that build system that is used by VS when you create a Project via the menu File/New Project  wizard

Comment: @KarolaN the project wizard has presets for all kinds of build systems, but the most common is msbuild, in which case it has a list of files in the *.vcxproj files.

Comment: @KarolaN - All files have a "Last change" time stamp. So the build system has to check the .cpp file and all the .h files it includes to see if any of them has been modified since the .cpp file was last compiled. And if so, it has to recompile that .cpp file. For the rest it already has up to date .obj files from previous build.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen "*Header files aren’t compiled, they are included in other source files*" - there is such a thing as **precompiled headers**, though

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know, I simplified since they’re not compiled by themselves to any meaningful output without source files. Adding header files and compiling doesn’t do anything to them without them being included